# Excluding certain values in SQL output

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to find the room code of lectures which are of 100 or more capacity and are free (i.e. not booked) on Tuesday at 12pm.

Data is stored in the `roomBooking` table, which has:

> bookingID
>
> roomCode
>
> moduleCode
>
> dayReq
>
> timeReq
>
> semester
>
> classSize

My query so far:

```
 SELECT rCode, capacity 
 FROM room
 INNER JOIN roomBooking
 ON room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode
 WHERE capacity >= 100;
```

I tried to use a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause, but could not get it right. My goal is to exclude the rooms that are booked at Tuesday at 12pm.

Comment: Are you looking for all Tuesdays at noon or a specific one?

Comment: Also, can you tell us kind of database you're using? (SQL-Server/Oracle/MySQL/etc)

Comment: @april4181 I'm looking for the rooms that are over that capacity but not the ones booked at Tuesday at 12

Comment: @april4181 Microsoft Access

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    rCode, 
    capacity 
FROM 
    room
     LEFT JOIN 
    roomBooking ON 
        room.rCode = roomBooking.roomCode AND
        roomBooking.dayReq = 'Tuesday' AND -- fix with the right value
        roomBooking.timeReq = '12:00' -- fix with the right value
WHERE 
    capacity >= 100 AND
    roomBooking.BookingID IS NULL -- this will exclude all rooms with bookings on that date/time
```

Comment: When I try this, I get "JOIN expression not supported" and roomBooking.dayReq = "Tuesday" is highlighted

Comment: My intent in posting that was that you would convert my hard-coded 'Tuesday' with a formula that would tell dayReq what you're interested in.  If you don't know how to do that, please tell me what the data type of that column is, show me a sample of an actual value from that column looks like, and define 'Tuesday' in the same format.  Then do the same for timeReq

Comment: I realize that might be confusing: I want to know if `dayReq` contains "Tuesday", "2014-11-11 00:00:00.000", "3", or something else like that ...

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS is the way to go, as you already assumed. You want to select rooms for which no roomBooking of a certain kind exists:

```
select * 
from room
where capacity >= 100
and not exists
(
  select *
  from roombooking
  where roomBooking.roomcode = room.rcode
  and dayreq = ...
  and timereq = ...
);
```

I didn't write the criteria for day and time, as I don't know what these fields contain exactly and what data type they are. Somehow you will get the weekday from dayreq and the time from timereq. (Shouldn't there also be a time span for how many hours the room is booked, btw?)

Comment: when I try this, I get an error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: Well, the only criteria are roomcode/rcode and capacity/100. I see no mismatch there. How did you write your dayrec and timereq expressions? What data types are the two? What do they contain?